# Android Studio- Code moving ahead before calling a function

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio

I am calling a function in Android Studio "On Create".

Something like this:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Config: On Create 00 " + getInput());


    public List<Object> getInput(){
        final List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = ref.child("Device").orderByChild("home").equalTo(homeID);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshots :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    result.add(dataSnapshots.getKey());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Config: get Input 2 " + result);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Config: On Create 02 " + result);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
        Log.i(TAG, "Config: On Create 01 " + result);
        return result;
    }
```

The sequence of logs generated is confusing me and I believe it is not as per the flow.
The sequence is: 
Log 1) Config On Create 01
Log 2) Config On Create 00
Log 3) Config get Input 2
Log 4) Config On Create 02

I believe Log 2 should come before Log 1
I am confused and also I am not getting the result as expected. Please help.

Comment: "I believe Log 2 should come before Log 1" -- no. `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is asynchronous. It will do its work on a background thread, calling your `ValueEventListener` when that work is completed. That will be *long* after `getInput()` returns.

Comment: Thanks. Got that. Also, the result is not showing up in Log 1 and Log2, Log 3 and 4 are giving results right.

Comment: You do not have a 3 or a 4.

Comment: This might help.   Log 3) Config get Input 2                     Log 4) Config On Create 02